# How to make a list of share_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am facing a design issue that could be summarized by the following class: A linked list of shared buffer where the linking element is a SharedBuffer

```
class SharedBuffer : public shared_ptr<Buffer> {
private:
    SharedBuffer    _next;

    SharedBuffer(Buffer* buffer) : shared_ptr<Buffer>(buffer) {}
    ~SharedBuffer() { 
        if (_next)
           _next.reset();
    }
};
```

This class is wrong because it references itself in its own definition. But that the idea. Any idea on making such a list of shared buffer?

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Buffer>>` ?

Comment: If your problem is that you don't want the backwards links of `std::list`, then there is `std::forward_list` for that.

Comment: Because I want my client's API to use a SharedBuffer, optionally linked with other SharedBuffer thu _next, not a vector of shared_ptr<Buffer>

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is

## You don't

There are many container classes in the stl. `std::vector<>`, `std::list<>` or whatever other container you are looking for. Do not roll your own. Please. You will only make mistakes and your time could be better spent working on your program logic instead of debugging a bad implementation of something, especially when good implementations are available for free.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Buffer>> sharedBuffers;
```

Comment: "You don't" is good here, but perhaps OP just wants reference counting on a shared buffer which should also support other shared operations (not just ownership).

Answer (score 0):

If your `SharedBuffer` really should stay a **Shared** object, just like `shared_ptr` is a shared "object" (object being pointer here, and sharing means shared ownership), but you want to have it reference-counted, you could simply hold a `shared_ptr` inside it rather than inheriting (which is a bad idea, especially considering the problems leading up to `make_shared`).

```
class SharedBuffer {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Buffer> _buffer;
    SharedBuffer            _next;

    SharedBuffer(Buffer* buffer) : _buffer{buffer} {}

    // note the following is now redundant, since it happens automatically
    /*~SharedBuffer() { 
        if (_next)
           _next.reset();
    }*/

    /* Other protected operations (e.g. read/write) */
};
```

Even better, you should already accept a `shared_ptr` in `SharedBuffer`'s constructor.